# Selectively loading/hiding columns in SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a table in my database that contains user accounts, along with model class to map its fields to an SQLAlchemy ORM class.

```
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    email = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

In the same table, I have columns that are only used in an admin context (user management, in this case), let's say a `comment` column for putting snarky comments which the user should never see (e.g. "*this person creates a lot of support noise, deprioritize*").

Now if I add said column to the model class, SQLAlchemy will load the column into the object and my current JSON serialization logic will expose it in the REST responses.

```
class Account(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accounts'
    email = Column(Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    comment = Column(Text)

    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, any]:
        """Serialize to dictionary and eventually JSON"""
        d = {}
        for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
            d[key] = getattr(self, key)
        return d
```

Is there a best practice for creating context-specific mappings of rows in the same table? I had a look at deferred columns and groups but that's not what I'm looking for.

Should I introduce an `AdminAccount` subclass of `Account` and load that instead in the administrative context? Or adding some kind of decorator to a column and make serialization context-dependent?